# How do I sync two or more waveforms in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, synchronization, waveform

I'll try to be more specific: I have several time histories of a signal which have pretty much all the same behaviour (sine waves) but all start at a different point in time. How do I automatically detect the initial time lag and delete it such that all sine waves start at the same instant in time?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to recreate the behavior of an oscilloscope. Could you post images or code that can be used to reproduce the signals. "Pretty much the same" is not very helpful. Is the signal static before the sine waves get underway?

Comment: Can I post images in comments? But anyway, just imagine you have 3 sinewaves of the same amplitude and frequency that start at a different instant in time. What I want to do is "sync" them such that they all start at the same instant. I've done this manually cutting the 3 vectors such that the initial offset is eliminated but I'm looking for a function that does exactly the same thing automatically. I've also tried to use 'xcorr' but what I get in return is either not really helpful or I don't know how to use it. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works pretty well under low noise conditions and fast sampling and may do depending on your requirements for accuracy. It uses a simple threshold and thus is subject to inaccuracy when things get noisy. Adjust `thresh` to a low value above the noise.

```
Nwav = 3;
Np = 100;
tmax = 50;
A = 1000;
Nz = Np/5;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
thresh = A/50;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



% generate some waveforms
t = [0:tmax/(Np-1):tmax].';
w = rand(1,Nwav);
offs = round(rand(1,Nwav)*100);
sig = [A*sin(t(1:end-Nz)*w) ; zeros(Nz,Nwav)] + randn(Np,Nwav);
for ii=1:Nwav
    sig(:,ii) = circshift(sig(:,ii),round(rand()*Nz));
end
figure, plot(t,sig)
hold on, plot(t,repmat(thresh,length(t),1),'k--')


% use the threshold and align the waveforms
for ii=1:Nwav
    [ir ic] = find(sig(:,ii)>thresh,1)
    sig(:,ii) = circshift(sig(:,ii),-ir+1);
end
figure, plot(t,sig)
hold on, plot(t,repmat(thresh,length(t),1),'k--')
```

There is room for improvement (noise filtering, slope detection) but this should get you started.

I also recommend you look into waveform processing toolboxes, in matlab central for instance.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I've kind of got it working! Everything is automatic except for the threshold! Sometimes I have to adjust it due to noise! I'm also using a low pass filter to reduce the noise but sometimes is not enough! Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2):

If you have two signals, x and y, each being a n x 1 matrix where y is a shifted version of x:

```
[c,lags] = xcorr(x,y); % c is the correlation, should have a clear peak
s = lags(c==max(c)); % s is the shift you need
y2 = circshift(y,s); % y2 should now overlap x
```

(Demo purposes only - I don't suggest you circshift your actual data). The shift you are looking for in this case should ideally be relatively small compared to the length of x and y.  A lot depends on the noise level and the nature of the offset.